# Excepção externa C0000006

Tags: delphi, exceção, delphi-10

Essa Semana eu estou a me bater nesse erro em algumas maquinas onde o sistema está rodando.

> ```
> Excepção externa C0000006 EXCEPTION_IN_PAGE_ERROR
> ```

As maquinas têm acesso ao sistema por uma pasta compartilhada na rede. Não sei como resolver isso.

Dar para resolver o erro via programação e como seria?

Comment: Isso é problema de arquivos: estão executando pela rede o aplicativo mas estão buscando algum arquivo na pasta compartilhada que não possuem acesso e/ou não existe. Pode ser também que ao executar pela pasta compartilhada, estão procurando por recursos enquanto aplicação executa na pasta temporária.

Comment: Mais tem maquinas que funciona tudo cretinho e em outras não... :(

Comment: Então tenta buscar os dados do event viewer das máquinas que ocorrem o erro para saber qual recurso que não consegue utilizar.

Comment: isso é erro de aplicação...tem que descobrir qual aplicação está dando esse erro, e repassar o problema para o desenvolvedor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta mensagem ocorre quando o seu sistema é iniciado pelo caminho ([UNC](http://ptcomputador.com/Networking/other-computer-networking/76951.html)) ou quando há um mapeamento para uma determinada unidade, ambos os casos acessando Servers Windows que utilizam bloco de controle de arquivo ([FCB](https://o-que-quer-dizer.blogspot.com/2015/06/bloco-de-controle-de-arquivos-fcb.html)) para todas as conexões de usuários.
*Por exemplo: \nome_servidor\acesso_sistema* em ambiente TS.

Esse problema foi relatado pela Microsoft várias vezes pelos desenvolvedores e usuários finais da Delphi, considerando também um problema com o gerenciamento de memória do Windows.

O incidente **External Exception C0000006** é um erro de página IO e poderá ocorrer quando o Windows tentar carregar a aplicação em partes na memória.

**1. Causa**

- Um aplicativo não é totalmente carregado na memória, o sistema
  operacional tenta buscar mais do aplicativo no disco HD para que ele
  continue em funcionamento.
- O sistema operacional não carrega a parte requerida do programa na memória e apresenta uma falta de página (*bloco de controle de arquivo - FCB*).
- Após a falha de página, o sistema operacional termina a aplicação com
  uma **ExternalException**, porque não pode continuar a executar a
  aplicação.
- Arquivo removido ou inacessível;

**2. Solução**

- ***Melhor Solução:*** Execute o aplicativo localmente, em vez de ser executado a partir de uma pasta compartilhada no mesmo servidor. Isso evita que o problema ocorra, o que indica que este é um problema no sistema operacional. Ao executar o aplicativo localmente em cada estação de trabalho, isso exigirá um modelo distribuído ou cliente/servidor para atualizações de aplicativos em oposição a um modelo centralizado (que era possível antes com um local de pasta compartilhada/caminho [UNC](http://ptcomputador.com/Networking/other-computer-networking/76951.html)).
- ***Solução possível:*** Adicionar diretiva do compilador ao projeto do aplicativo:

  ```
  {$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP}
  {$DEFINE IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE = $ 8000}
  {$SetPEOptFlags IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE}
  {$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED or
           IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP or
           IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP}
  ```

Esta diretiva forçará o programa a ser completamente carregado na memória e pode impedir que a exceção externa ocorra aleatoriamente.

A Microsoft publicou um *[hot-fix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818528)* para abordar uma instância do problema relatado em http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294816.

Veja também esta orientação no site da [embarcadero](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=171717).